# Deep Comparision of Two Java Objects

Tags: java, xml, reflection, comparison, equals

Already referred few question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449001/is-there-a-java-reflection-utility-to-do-a-deep-comparison-of-two-objects) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632664/deep-reflective-compare-equals).

Use Case -

1.) Given any `Two objects`, `compare` both of them property by property.

2.) It will contains `Collections` also, now compare collections of both the objects, now inside collection same data can be upside down, meaning say i have `List<Address>`, it contains two entries in both (say `Residential Address`, `Office Address`), but in both list the data may be at different indexes.

3.) Need to create `3rd Object` of same type, with similar data copied, and properties set to null with different data.

4.) It might have reference classes as well.

I tired many solutions but stuck somewhere or the other, i am thinking of writing some generic solution. Though of `generating two xml's` out of the two objects and then comparing node by node, but just want to get more options.

Or How much `Java reflection` is stronger in this case.

Comment: This sounds really difficult.  I would not use reflection, it won't be able to access private fields and private objects reliably.  Maybe something like Kryo and parse the output, but that's pretty hairy.

Comment: @markspace hi, just posted the answer for your comment, dnt knw if i have to post as an answer or comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer to @markspace question.

To access a `private field` you will need to call the `Class.getDeclaredField(String name)` or `Class.getDeclaredFields()` method. The methods `Class.getField(String name)` and `Class.getFields()` methods only `return public fields`, so they won't work.

To access a `private method` you will need to call the `Class.getDeclaredMethod(String name, Class[] parameterTypes)` or `Class.getDeclaredMethods()` method. The methods `Class.getMethod(String name, Class[] parameterTypes)` and `Class.getMethods()` methods only `return public methods`.

`XMLUnit` will work, it compares the list references recursively, also it has option to exclude fields which you do not wish to compare.

```
 String expectedXML = "some xml";
 String actualXML = "some xml";

 DetailedDiff diff1 = new DetailedDiff(XMLUnit.compareXML(expectedXML, actualXML));
 diff1.overrideElementQualifier(new RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier());
 System.out.println("Differences found: " + diff1.getAllDifferences().toString());
```

**RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier**

> Compares all Element and Text nodes in two pieces of XML. Allows
>   elements of complex, deeply nested types that are returned in
>   different orders but have the same content to be recognized as
>   comparable.