# Deep recursive objects comparison (once again)

Tags: java, reflection, compare

There are two similar questions on SO:

[Is there a Java utility to do a deep comparison of two objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449001/is-there-a-java-reflection-utility-to-do-a-deep-comparison-of-two-objects)

[Deep reflective compare equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632664/deep-reflective-compare-equals)

but, it is funny, none of them gives a fully correct answer to the question.

What I and other questions' authors really want, is some method in some library which will just tell whether the given two objects are equal or not:

`boolean deepEquals(Object obj1, Object obj2)`

i.e. without throwing any exception and so on.

`apache`'s `EqualsBuilder` is not the solution, because it doesn't deep compare.

`Unitils` seems also be a bad decision, because its method do not return `true` or `false`; it just throws an exception if comparison has failed. Of course, it could be used like this:

`Difference difference = ReflectionComparatorFactory.createRefectionComparator(new ReflectionComparatorMode[]{ReflectionComparatorMode.LENIENT_ORDER, ReflectionComparatorMode.IGNORE_DEFAULTS}).getDifference(oldObject, newObject);`

but it seems to be very ugly, and `unitils` library entirely seems to be too heavy for the required compare purposes.

Furthermore, it is quite clear how to create such `deepEquals` by myself, but it is unlikely that there aren't common used libraries which contain an already implemented method like this. Any ideas?

Comment: Recursive comparison is not trivial. Look at the `EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals` method - it let's you specify what fields to not compare and how far to reach in class hierarchy tree when inheritance is used. Now if you have a nested object which you want to also compare using reflection, how can you tell what fields to ignore? If you don't care, then it is simple to wrap `EqualsBuilder` implementation to achieve what you need. Otherwise you may need to use annotations or a registry to tell for what class what fields to not compare.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the Apache `EqualsBuilder` is a terrible answer, but for a simple interface that does what you want, you would need to wrap the call a bit. Here's an example.

```
public static <T> boolean matches(T actual, T expected, String... excludedFields) {
    assert actual != null;
    assert expected != null;
    boolean matches = EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(actual, expected,
            false /* testTransients */,
            null /* reflectUpToClass */,
            true /* testRecursive */,
            excludedFields);
    if (!matches) {
        log.warn("Actual result doesn't match.");
        logComparison(actual, expected);
    }
    return matches;
}

public static <T>  void logComparison(T actual, T expected) {
    //Making sure hashcodes don't thrown an exception
    assert actual.hashCode() > Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    assert expected.hashCode() > Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    log.warn("Expected: \n" + reflectionToString(expected));
    log.warn("Actual: \n" + reflectionToString(actual));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Java 1.7 has `Objects.deepEquals(Object a, Object b)`

Unfortunately `Unitils`'s `ReflectionAssert` class does not have an accompanying method that returns `true` or `false`. You can try:

https://github.com/jdereg/java-util

whose `DeepEquals` class has `DeepEquals.deepEquals(Object a, Object b)` and `DeepEquals.deepHashCode(Object o)` methods which you can use to override your class's `equals` and `hashCode` methods or use in an external `Comparator` or `Equivalence`.

Note: This DeepEquals implementation has a limitation. If the class has a user defined overridden equals methods, that will take precedence.

Comment: The author of the question did not write it explicitly, but I think based on referenced questions, that he wants a reflection equals, that is comparing objects, without implementing `equals` method on them. The `Objects.deepEquals(Object a, Object b)` does not compare using reflection. It relies on `equals` method and `deep` part refers to comparing arrays, not fields with reference types.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking into testing, AssertJ offers a recursive comparison function:

```
assertThat(new).usingRecursiveComparison().isEqualTo(old);
```

See AssertJ's documentation for details: https://assertj.github.io/doc/#basic-usage

Prerequisites for using AssertJ:

import:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;
```

maven dependency:

```
    <!-- test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.19.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```