# How do I make Groovy Spock test compare invocation parameters with equals rather than ==

Tags: groovy, spock, lombok

I have this Groovy test for my Spring application.

```
given:
    def mapProperties = new JSONObject().put(
      "eligibility", "true").put(
      "group", "group1")
when:
    trackingService.sendUnifiedOnboardingAssignmentUserUpdate()
then:
    1 * trackingCollector.send(new UserUpdate(mapProperties))
```

Tracking Collector is external and defined as a Spring Bean in the Specification I am extending.

```
@SpringBean
TrackingCollector trackingCollector = Mock()
```

`trackingService` is in my domain layer and is Autowired

The test should run successfully, but it's not.

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * trackingCollector.send(new UserUpdate(mapProperties))   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

1 * trackingCollector.send(UserUpdate(super=Event(properties={"group":"group1","eligibility":"true"})))
One or more arguments(s) didn't match:
0: argument == expected
   |        |  |
   |        |  UserUpdate(super=Event(properties={"group":"group1","eligibility":"true"})) (com.package.tracking.collector.UserUpdate@4fe5aac9)
   |        false
   UserUpdate(super=Event(properties={"group":"group1","eligibility":"true"})) (com.package.tracking.collector.UserUpdate@48bb5a69)
```

The only different thing is the `@....`. But why is Groovy not checking the actual value of the object and chooses to compare the objects instead? What do I need to do to make the test pass in this case?

Comment: Are `UserUpdate` and `Event` actually implementing `equals`, or are they using the default `Object.equals`?

Comment: Very good question! @LeonardBrünings `UserUpdate` extends `Event` in a separate library. `UserUpdate` has `@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)` from Lombok,  which means basically calling the superclass for equals. And then `Event` has `@Data` from Lombok, which also implements equals.

Comment: Either way, either `equals` or `hashCode` or both are not doing the thing you expect in your case. Where is your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Nobody can debug your incomplete set of snippets.

Comment: The code base is extremely big, I did try to produce an MCVE, but without including a lot more information, I just don't see how it's possible. I've already added what Lombok annotations I use for the relevant classes. I suspect it's either a Lombok thing where `@Data` is not giving me the `equals` function I want, or a Groovy+Spock thing where the invocation parameter wants an exact match under the hood, comparing references, not values. I was looking for an answer that helped answer this specific question, as well as maybe help me fix it.

Comment: Spock uses [Groovy truth](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#the-groovy-truth) so it will simply compare those two objects with `equals`. What happens if you manually construct two separate instances, and just do `assert a == b` on them?

Comment: Doing that still fails the assertion. That's good news, the scope of the problem is narrowed down. So this means that defining another `equals` method that just checks every key+value pair of the `JSONObject` of `UserUpdate` in the library rather than using the Lombok basic `equals` (whatever that is) will probably fix my issue. I'll give this a go and update my question accordingly. Still wondering if there's a more elegant, Spock-only solution to this. Like, how do I make it check value of parameters of invocations over reference?

Comment: Well, as I said it doesn't do the Java `==`, but calls `equals`, and if that is properly implemented it will do what you want. If you don't want to properly implement it, then using [reflective equals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9633089/2145769) could work for your use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spock uses [Groovy truth](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#the-groovy-truth), so it will simply compare those two objects with `equals`, or `compareTo` if they are implementing `Comparable`.

That the output contains the object id is a red-herring, Spock only includes it in the output when two objects have the same string rendering, to make it easier to figure out what is wrong.

If you can't fix the `equals` implementation, you could use a [code argument constraint](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.3/all_in_one.html#_code_constraint) to manually check for the necessary values.

As noted in the comments your problems stems from the fact, that the equals method is not properly implemented for your use-case.