# Is there an existing Java function that compares two objects via reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Java reflection utility to do a deep comparison of two objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449001/is-there-a-java-reflection-utility-to-do-a-deep-comparison-of-two-objects)

I want to create a generic object comparison method like this -

```
public static boolean objectsAreEqual(Object A, Object B)
   {
        // ensure objects belong to the same class
        // compare object fields via reflection
        // if all fields match, then return true else return false
   }
```

Is there an existing implementation for this?

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html Or do you want it to work recursively?

Comment: @biziclop Yes, recursively. EqualsBuilder seems to have that ability. So thanks.

Comment: Umm, I seem to have linked to an old version of the documentation but I can't change it now, so everyone be warned.