# Assert.assertEquals() fails for custom class objects

Tags: java, junit

Even though I have two data objects of a custom class which are equal w.r.t all the variables, assertEquals() method is failing. What am I missing here?

Comment: We can not see what you miss, if you not show what you have.

Comment: Why do you ask a question if you post a self-answer in the very same minute?

Comment: I figured out what was the problem. And I got a fix for it. I thought of sharing. If so many negativity is there about that, I am sorry. I should've kept it myself I guess.

Comment: @JavaKumara don't misinterpret the comment as hate, it's not about you it's about the question, Stackoverflow is not a forum, it's a Q&A site that. And this sites has guidelines like avoiding duplicate questions, unclear questions, minimum understanding of the problem, etc... All of that to create a site where content is great. There's already multiple questions that have been answered in the past on this topic by the way : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147297/how-do-i-assert-equality-on-two-classes-without-an-equals-method

Comment: Thanks @Brice. I wasn't aware of the guidelines. Will go through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparison to check if its equals are not happens with the help of the equals() function. You need to override this method in your custom class.

```html
public boolean equals(Object obj) { }
```

Please also make sure you override hashCode() method as well.

Comment: You figured out your issue very quickly

Comment: @ToYonos Because he just asked to answer it himself. This would be a ok, if the question would have a higher quality.

Answer (score 4):

For comparing two objects you need to override the `equals()` method of the `Object` class.

When you create two objects of a class, say class `A`, then the objects are different even if they have all the same variables. This is because the equals method or `==` both check if the reference of the objects are pointing to the same object.

```
Object o1 = new A();
Object o2 = new A();
o1.equals(o2);
```

Here the equals method will return false, even if all the fields are `null` or even if you assign same values to both the objects.

```
Object o1 = new A();
Object o2 = o1;
o1.equals(o2);
```

Here the equals method will return true, because the object is only one, and both `o1`, `o2` references are pointing to same object.

What you can do is override the `equals` method

```
public class A {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj==this) return true;
        if (obj==null || obj.getClass()!=this.getClass()) return false;
        return (this.id==((A) obj).id);
    }
    // You must also override hashCode() method
}
```

Here we say objects of class `A` are equal if they have same id. You can do same for multiple fields.

Comment: Take out `implements Comparator<A>`.

Comment: He should also override the `hashCode` method.

Comment: Also "`? true : false`" is superfluous. And why not just compare the `id`s with `==`?

Comment: made the changes, thanks for pointing

Comment: Still shouldn't say `implements Comparable<T>`. Also your `equals` method will throw a `ClassCastException` if it is given anything other than an instance of `A`.