# AssertEquals dosen't work

Tags: java, junit

I have a problem with AssertEquals in JUnit because i try to compare two istance of objects , i get this error :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: com.euris.Price<Price [1p 19s 2d -2a]> but was: com.euris.Price<Price [1p 19s 2d -2a]>
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
at com.euris.exercise.ExerciseApplicationTests.contextLoads(ExerciseApplicationTests.java:31)
mework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Show the code for `com.euris.Price`. This depends more on the class being compared than on JUnit

Comment: Did you override `equals` method in `com.euris.Price`

Comment: `AssertEquals` has been used by a lot of people. Any bugs have likely been found and fixed ages ago. If it doesn't seem to work, you should question your own code before you question the JUnit code.

Comment: To reinforce @Andreas' point, `assertEquals` is covered by tests. If it didn't work, it would be known.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yeah, what a novel concept: The JUnit code is itself unit tested. Who'd have thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is Price is a custom Object you have to override equals method for AssertEquals to work . I hope this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864477/assert-assertequals-fails-for-custom-class-objects) helps.

Comment: You think? I mean, it's a good guess, but a guess nonetheless. Ask for clarification in a comment, once you have the [50 rep needed for that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I override equals method and it works thanks

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks for valuable input.