# JUnit - Compare Value Objects

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

short question: I have the situation that I want to compare value objects in my JUnit tests. Those value objects only have a few fields of different types (but mostly primitive types). I create one object from an xml file and the other from a dataset from my database.

I solved it by overriding the equals method in my value object class and then compare those two by assertEquals(o1, o2).
I want to know if there is another solution for this task. Maybe a solution with which I don't have to write equals methods for every value class (there are a few...)

I already experimented with Hamcrest, but not really successful. I tried assertThat(o2, is(equalTo(o1)));
If the object is equal, the JUnit test is successful, but if not, the test is not failing but exits with an exception (don't think that's how it should work, right?)

I also thought of something with reflection to automatically compare all fields of the classes, but I don't know how to start.

Do you have a suggestion how something like this is solved the most elegant way?

Comment: equals is the right way, or you could compare individual fields of those objects using getters.

Comment: This SO post might contain some solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12147297/1291150

Comment: Value objects should always override the equals method, because to say an object is a value object is to say that there can exist a different object that is equivalent to this object, and the equals method indicates which other objects are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually mentioned the 3 most popular techniques:
1. implement "good" equals method and use it from unit test as well. 
2. use series of `assertEquals()`
3. Use `assertThat()`

I personally used all these techniques found all of them pretty useful; the choice depends on concrete requirements. Sometimes I created comaprison utility class that contained series of `assert` methods for my value objects. This helps to re-use assertion code in different unit tests.

According to my experience it is good idea to implement good `equals()`, `hashCode()` and `toString()` for all value objects. This is not too difficult. You can use `EqualsBuilder`, `HashCodeBuilder` and `ToSringBuilder` from Apache commons or utilities of `Object` introduced in java 7. This is up to you.

If performance is not an issue (IMHO correct for 99.999% of real applications) use reflection based builders (from apache commons). This makes the implementations very simple and maintenance-less.

In most cases using `equals()` in unit test is good enough. However if it is not good, use `assertThat()` or seriece of `assertEquals()` according to your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, I think the EqualsBuilder is exactly what I was looking for =) Problem solved, and thanks for the additional explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Like the AlexR's answer states it is a good idea to implement good `equals()`, `hashCode()` and `toString()` methods and Apache commons has great helpers for that if performance is not the most important concern (and for unit testing it is not).

I had a similar test requirement in the past and there I did not just want to hear **that** the value object was different but also see **which properties were different** (and not just the first but all). I created a helper (using Spring's BeanWrapper) to do just that, it is available in: https://bitbucket.org/fhoeben/hsac-test and allows you to call `UnitTestHelper.assertEqualsWithDiff(T expected, T actual)` in you unit tests

```
/**
 * Checks whether expected and actual are equal, and if not shows which
 * properties differ.
 * @param expected expected object.
 * @param actual actual object
 * @param <T> object type.
 */
public static <T> void assertEqualsWithDiff(T expected, T actual) {
    Map<String, String[]> diffs = getDiffs(null, expected, actual);

    if (!diffs.isEmpty()) {
        StringBuilder diffString = new StringBuilder();
        for (Entry<String, String[]> diff : diffs.entrySet()) {
            appendDiff(diffString, diff);
        }
        fail(diffs.size() + " difference(s) between expected and actual:\n" + diffString);
    }
}

private static void appendDiff(StringBuilder diffString, Entry<String, String[]> diff) {
    String propertyName = diff.getKey();
    String[] value = diff.getValue();
    String expectedValue = value[0];
    String actualValue = value[1];

    diffString.append(propertyName);
    diffString.append(": '");
    diffString.append(expectedValue);
    diffString.append("' <> '");
    diffString.append(actualValue);
    diffString.append("'\n");
}

private static Map<String, String[]> getDiffs(String path, Object expected, Object actual) {
    Map<String, String[]> diffs = Collections.emptyMap();
    if (expected == null) {
        if (actual != null) {
            diffs = createDiff(path, expected, actual);
        }
    } else if (!expected.equals(actual)) {
        if (actual == null
                || isInstanceOfSimpleClass(expected)) {
            diffs = createDiff(path, expected, actual);
        } else if (expected instanceof List) {
            diffs = listDiffs(path, (List) expected, (List) actual);
        } else {
            diffs = getNestedDiffs(path, expected, actual);
        }
        if (diffs.isEmpty() && !(expected instanceof JAXBElement)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Found elements that are not equal, "
                    + "but not able to determine difference, "
                    + path);
        }
    }
    return diffs;
}

private static boolean isInstanceOfSimpleClass(Object expected) {
    return expected instanceof Enum
            || expected instanceof String
            || expected instanceof XMLGregorianCalendar
            || expected instanceof Number
            || expected instanceof Boolean;
}

private static Map<String, String[]> listDiffs(String path, List expectedList, List actualList) {
    Map<String, String[]> diffs = new LinkedHashMap<String, String[]>();
    String pathFormat = path + "[%s]";
    for (int i = 0; i < expectedList.size(); i++) {
        String nestedPath = String.format(pathFormat, i);
        Object expected = expectedList.get(i);
        Map<String, String[]> elementDiffs;
        if (actualList.size() > i) {
            Object actual = actualList.get(i);
            elementDiffs = getDiffs(nestedPath, expected, actual);
        } else {
            elementDiffs = createDiff(nestedPath, expected, "<no element>");
        }
        diffs.putAll(elementDiffs);
    }
    for (int i = expectedList.size(); i < actualList.size(); i++) {
        String nestedPath = String.format(pathFormat, i);
        diffs.put(nestedPath, createDiff("<no element>", actualList.get(i)));
    }
    return diffs;
}

private static Map<String, String[]> getNestedDiffs(String path, Object expected, Object actual) {
    Map<String, String[]> diffs = new LinkedHashMap<String, String[]>(0);
    BeanWrapper expectedWrapper = getWrapper(expected);
    BeanWrapper actualWrapper = getWrapper(actual);
    PropertyDescriptor[] descriptors = expectedWrapper.getPropertyDescriptors();
    for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : descriptors) {
        String propertyName = propertyDescriptor.getName();
        Map<String, String[]> nestedDiffs =
                getNestedDiffs(path, propertyName,
                        expectedWrapper, actualWrapper);
        diffs.putAll(nestedDiffs);
    }
    return diffs;
}

private static Map<String, String[]> getNestedDiffs(
        String path,
        String propertyName,
        BeanWrapper expectedWrapper,
        BeanWrapper actualWrapper) {
    String nestedPath = propertyName;
    if (path != null) {
        nestedPath = path + "." + propertyName;
    }
    Object expectedValue = getValue(expectedWrapper, propertyName);
    Object actualValue = getValue(actualWrapper, propertyName);
    return getDiffs(nestedPath, expectedValue, actualValue);
}

private static Map<String, String[]> createDiff(String path, Object expected, Object actual) {
    return Collections.singletonMap(path, createDiff(expected, actual));
}

private static String[] createDiff(Object expected, Object actual) {
    return new String[] {getString(expected), getString(actual)};
}

private static String getString(Object value) {
    return String.valueOf(value);
}

private static Object getValue(BeanWrapper wrapper, String propertyName) {
    Object result = null;
    if (wrapper.isReadableProperty(propertyName)) {
        result = wrapper.getPropertyValue(propertyName);
    } else {
        PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = wrapper.getPropertyDescriptor(propertyName);
        Class<?> propertyType = propertyDescriptor.getPropertyType();
        if (Boolean.class.equals(propertyType)) {
            String name = StringUtils.capitalize(propertyName);
            Object expected = wrapper.getWrappedInstance();
            Method m = ReflectionUtils.findMethod(expected.getClass(), "is" + name);
            if (m != null && m.getReturnType().equals(Boolean.class)) {
                result = ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(m, expected);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(createErrorMsg(wrapper, propertyName));
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(createErrorMsg(wrapper, propertyName));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private static String createErrorMsg(BeanWrapper wrapper, String propertyName) {
    return propertyName + " can not be read on: " + wrapper.getWrappedClass();
}

private static <T> BeanWrapper getWrapper(T instance) {
    BeanWrapper wrapper = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(instance);
    wrapper.setAutoGrowNestedPaths(true);
    return wrapper;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The library [Hamcrest 1.3 Utility Matchers](https://github.com/NitorCreations/matchers) has a special matcher that uses reflection instead of equals.

```
assertThat(obj1, reflectEquals(obj2));
```