# JUnit what better way to use assertEquals between two objects without defining equals method

Tags: java, junit

I want to know what could be the better way to use

> assertEquals()

between two objects without defining

> equals()

method.

I wanted to use the org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder :
Assert.assertTrue(EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(expected,actual));

But i read in the documentation that it is not the best way to compare two objects : [COMMONS Doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html#reflectionEquals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String...)).

Also I would like to find an open source library that can do that or even better : no library.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I assert equality on two classes without an equals method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147297/how-do-i-assert-equality-on-two-classes-without-an-equals-method)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the advice regarding problems with the SecurityManager does not apply to your test code because you have control over the environment where your tests are running.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can use something like:

```
assertThat(Object1, is(Object2));
```

Using [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/overview-summary.html).

Comment: Since he doesn't define equals, this won't work. A custom matcher, however, will.

Answer (score -1):

You could auto generate equals if this is an option for you using Lombok project:
https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode.html