# Java Testing Deep not equals

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, assert, assertj

I am struggling to find a way to test two object for deep non-equality (field by field) using jUnit or/and AssertJ.

Is there any way?

Something like this.

```
not(assertThat(mSubjectManager.getSubjectById(subjectId))
                .isEqualToComparingFieldByField(subject));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I assert equality on two classes without an equals method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147297/how-do-i-assert-equality-on-two-classes-without-an-equals-method)

Comment: Junit has assertNotEquals, but you need to define .equals() for that object yourself

Comment: This would be a weird test. If you want something to be not equal you should check every field that must differ. I can't think of a situation where what you're asking for is a valid case.

Answer (score 0):

With AssertJ, I think you could create a [`Condition`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-conditions.html) wrapping a deep equals check and make it fails if deep equals, a bit weird but could work.