# create object expressions with by content equality behavior

Tags: kotlin, equality

I want to create on-the-fly objects using object expressions but I would like to compare them by their contents. Is there an easy way to write it without implementing `equals` and `hashCode`?

To make it more concrete, what would be the smallest change to make the assertion of this test pass?

```
@Test
fun `an object comparison test`() {
    val obj1 = object {
        val x = 1
    }
    val obj2 = object {
        val x = 1
    }

    assertEquals<Any>(obj1, obj2)
}
```

Comment: No, there is no way. These two objects are instances of two different classes with no relationship between each other. Whenever the compiler or IDE generates `equals()` for you, it requires that the objects have the same class.

Comment: Thanks @yole. That makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without implementing a corresponding `equals` (at least) they will never be equal. That's the nature of every `object` or `instance` you create. Exceptions to that are `data class` instances which actually already supply an appropriate `equals()`/`hashCode()` for you.

So

```
data class Some(val value : String)

println(Some("one") == Some("one"))
```

will actually print `true` even though these are two distinct instances.

The easiest is probably to supply your own assertion function (may it be via reflection or not) or use a reflective assertion equals-method if your test framework supplies it.
In the latter case maybe the following is interesting for you: [How do I assert equality on two classes without an equals method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147297/how-do-i-assert-equality-on-two-classes-without-an-equals-method)