# EqualsBuilder using as comparator for attributes

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-lang

If you know  [EqualsBuilder from apache commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) you know that you can use it for implementing equals methods with reflection. It seems to work well but since I am using third party software I need to change its behavior. I need a generic comparator which checks all attributes and it can not be assumed that attribut-objects have an implemented equals method, but EqualsBuilder assumes it.

In detail I want to change `public EqualsBuilder append(Object lhs, Object rhs)` so that instead of calling `isEquals = lhs.equals(rhs)` EqualsBuilder should be used for this object too. Something like `isEquals = EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(lhs, rhs, false);`

Overriding the method is possible but it will not be called because EqualsBuilder creates an object of its own. Therefore I need to tell EqualBuilder to use my RecursiveEquilbuilder object.

Any ideas?

Comment: Using CompareToBuilder does not help, because it assumes that an attribute implements Comparable. :-(

Comment: I've created a feature request that should address this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-1034.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit old, but I hope it helps.

I run into the same problem that you, and I found that [the most voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1449051/1776630) (not the one picked by the author) of this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1449001/1776630), is the most suitable solution for you.

Basically, it consist on using the library called [Unitils](http://www.unitils.org/summary.html).

This is the use:

```
User user1 = new User(1, "John", "Doe");
User user2 = new User(1, "John", "Doe");
assertReflectionEquals(user1, user2);
```

Which will pass even if the class `User` doesn't implement `equals()`. You can see more examples and a really cool assert called `assertLenientEquals` in their [tutorial](http://www.unitils.org/tutorial-reflectionassert.html).