# Check objects equality without equals overriding in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, equals

Are there any utils in java which allow to check objects equality without *equals* overriding? For some reasons I don't want to provide my class with equals method.
I need something like *SomeUtils.equals(a,b)* in my unit test which compares all object fields (via reflection I guess).

Comment: I think  you got your answer, do it with reflection.... I don't really see what is the question here.

Comment: I don't want to do this by myself. I looking for prepared solution.

Comment: And what if your fields are not primitives? Should these objects also be compared by fields?

Comment: In that case the question is off-topic as a recommendation question...

Comment: Why don't you want to override [i]equals[/i], it can do no harm to your application in anyway and other methods then can check properly if object a equals object b. Doing it via reflection is a hassle and is everything but efficient

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html

Comment: This is a duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449001/is-there-a-java-reflection-utility-to-do-a-deep-comparison-of-two-objects

Comment: @TagirValeev equals should be used for not primitives fields in my case

Comment: @engineercoding  I m not owner of that class and can't access it source code

Comment: So? Apply `equals` recursively if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj);` in [Apache Commons EqualsBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html)

Comment: Thanks! That is I'm looking for. As mention by @bhspencer, my question is duplication for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449001/is-there-a-java-reflection-utility-to-do-a-deep-comparison-of-two-objects

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: @fuat What does not work about it?