# Is it possible to have a generic class where the type is an array of unknown dimension?

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to have a class `MyClass<T>` where `T` is a one dimensional or multidimensional array of integers? If so, and assuming that there's a field in the class of type `T`, how would I go about writing the `equals` method?

Comment: What is your requirement that 2 `MyClass` instances are equal?

Comment: That all fields are equal.

Comment: Then call the `equals` method on all of them. And as for your first question, why not check yourself?

Comment: That won't give the correct result. `T` is an array so calling `equals` on it will merely compare references, not do an element by element comparison.

Comment: Then we're back to the original issue where the arguments to `Arrays.equals` are of type `Object[]` and the compiler doesn't know that `T` is an array.

Comment: The compiler can't know what `T` is when you write the `equals` method. It only knows it once you declare it somewhere. You can check what `T` is yourself. Can you edit the question to be very specific on what you want to do and what the problem is? "How to write an equals method" is too general and explained many times on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to switch on the actual class and handle array-of-primitives separately, you can just wrap it in one more layer of array and use `Arrays.deepEquals()`:

```
Arrays.deepEquals(new Object[]{t}, new Object[]{other.t})
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.*;

public class A<T>
{
   private final T _t;
   public A(T t) { _t = t; }
   public void doSmth() { System.out.println(_t); }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      { 
                A<Integer> x = new A<>(10);
                x.doSmth();
      }

      { 
            Integer[] a = new Integer[5];
            A<Integer[]> x = new A<>(a);
            x.doSmth();
      }

      { 
            List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            A<List<Integer>> x = new A<>(a);
            x.doSmth();
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work when you try to implement `equals`. If you try `Arrays.deepEquals(this._t, other._t)` the compiler can't tell that `_t` is an array, you also can't cast it with `(Object[]) _t` as it's an array of primitives.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449001/is-there-a-java-reflection-utility-to-do-a-deep-comparison-of-two-objects

Comment: I belive that won't work either at it simply calls `equals` on every field.

Comment: Nope. Replies there suggest serialize, compare serialized data as a possible solution.