# How to compare two objects( with unsorted value) in java

Tags: java, sorting

```
Object a1= "[{"rdf:resource":"record\/16777228-43386050"},{"rdf:resource":"record\/16777228-43386055"},{"rdf:resource":"record\/16777228-43386057"},{"rdf:resource":"record\/16777228-43386059"}]"

Object a2= "[{"rdf:resource":"record\/16777228-43386059"},{"rdf:resource":"record\/16777228-43386057"},{"rdf:resource":"record\/16777228-43386055"},{"rdf:resource":"record\/16777228-43386050"}]"
```

Above Objects a1 & a2 , both are same, only the order in which they retrieved is different.

How to compare the above objects in such a way, that should return true

Comment: Are those strings? Arrays? JSON? This doesn't compile in Java (and neither in any other language that I know of). Can you give provide a [minimal, reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: that code won't run, you are missing a lot of "\" before the ' " '. also this is json code... decode it and check for equality

Comment: its a JSONObject. And the above value is sample one, i have removed some values, since its confidential

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Java reflection utility to do a deep comparison of two objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449001/is-there-a-java-reflection-utility-to-do-a-deep-comparison-of-two-objects)

Comment: As its presented in a current form its a string that inside can be treated as JSON... To clarify this point please add what is `a1.getClass().getName()`

Comment: @MarkBramnik   : JSONObject response="some response"; for( Object key: a1.keySet()){Object a1=response.get(key);  This is how value of a1 is fetched

Comment: its still says nothing about the type of a1...

Answer (score 1):

**You can override override hashCode() and equals() method.**

First of all, create a java class that will represent your json object like below class.

```
class JSONObject{
  private String rdfResource;
  // setter/getter

  //override hashCode() and equals() method

}
```

After that convert json array to java object array.

Finally convert java array object to json.

Comment: This *would* make a good answer if you'd provide a complete, working example.